# In a Corda Node when and how do the following tables fit into picture

Tags: corda

`NODE_TRANSACTION_MAPPINGS` table `(TX_ID ,STATE_MACHINE_RUN_ID)`,
`NODE_CHECKPOINTS` table  `(checkpoint Id, checkpoint Value)`and
`NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table.

What I think I understand is first Tx info is added to `node_transactions` table (irrespective to the validity of the Tx ) then it gets added to `node_transaction_mappings` then we update the checkpoint. (what are these checkpoints as we update this at each step, an enum to understand would help :).

Also, when do we put the Tx values `node_transactions` table? do we update any table once we send/receive a message from artemis?.

In short, do we have a transaction lifecycle somewhere? as in after what step what gets updated? Will make it easier to debug a Transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `ReceiveTransactionFlow` is invoked, the following process happens for **every** individual transaction received:

- The node creates a new DB transaction
- As part of the existing DB transaction, the node adds a checkpoint to the `NODE_CHECKPOINTS` table
- The node receives the Corda transaction from the counterparty
- As part of the existing DB transaction, the node updates the `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table
- As part of the existing DB transaction, the node updates the `NODE_TRANSACTION_MAPPINGS` table
- The node commits the DB transaction